# Plotting Predicted Probabilities of Weighted Ordinal Logistic Regression

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, logistic-regression

I'm doing a replication of an article for a class in R and need some help turning my predicted probabilities into the [plot they made.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmqWS.png) for the first plot of figure 1 of  [this article](https://www.dropbox.com/s/45gdryvb8x0amdj/slDVzN-10.1017%40S0003055419000534.pdf?dl=0).

Data for the article can be found [here](https://dataverse.harvard.edu/dataset.xhtml?persistentId=doi:10.7910/DVN/RJL2DK).

Note: I recommend using the .tab and not the .rdata. The .rdata made it difficult to complete these analyses. If you ever run into this problem, just message me here and I'll send you my full code.

I first completed my weighted ordinal logistic regression

```
library(MASS) # Weighted Ordinal Logistic Regression
ordlogit1<-polr(affectpol_o ~ empconc + empdist +emppers +empfant +pidext +ideoext +news +dem +educ +age +male +white +inc3miss_c, data=table1, method=c("logistic"), Hess=T, weights=table1$weight_group)
```

I end up with these [regression coefficients](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qwlH.png).

how do I plot the predicted probabilities and make a plot with the predicted probabilities and confidence intervals?

Thanks for your help

NOTE: edited to make it usable for other researchers

Comment: I have now made some progress but am still a bit stuck with how to make confidence intervals around the line. The second answer here assumes im still using that table of predicted probabilities, which I'm not anymore. I am using the code from answer 1.

Answer (score 0):

```
library(glm.predict)
library(VGAM)
for (i in 1:length(seq(from=0, to=1, by=.01)))
  {
  newdata3 <- data.frame(empconc=seq(from=0, to=1, by=.01)[i] ,
                         empdist= mean(table1$empdist,na.rm=TRUE),
                         emppers=mean(table1$emppers,na.rm=TRUE),
                         empfant=mean(table1$empfant,na.rm=TRUE),
                         pidext=mean(table1$pidext,na.rm=TRUE),
                         ideoext=mean(table1$ideoext,na.rm=TRUE),
                         news=mean(table1$news,na.rm=TRUE),
                         dem=1, 
                         educ=mean(table1$educ,na.rm=TRUE), 
                         age=mean(table1$age,na.rm=TRUE), 
                         male=0,
                         white=1,
                         inc3miss_c2=0,
                         inc3miss_c3=0,
                         inc3miss_c4=0)
 newdata3<-as.matrix(newdata3)
   if(i==1){
    prob<-data.frame(basepredict(ordlogit1,newdata3),
                     -6:6)
    prob<-data.frame(prob,seq(from=0, to=1, by=.01)[i])
  }else{
    temp<-data.frame(basepredict(ordlogit1,newdata3),
                     -6:6)
    temp<-data.frame(temp,seq(from=0, to=1, by=.01)[i])
    prob<-rbind(prob,temp)
  }
}

colnames(prob)<-c("mean","lower_bound","upper_bound","affectpol_o","empconc")

library(ggplot2)
ggplot(prob%>%filter(affectpol_o==6))+geom_line(aes(x=empconc,y=mean))+
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=empconc,ymin=lower_bound, ymax=upper_bound),alpha=0.2) +scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,0.6))
```

Answer (score 0):

This gets pretty close, starting with your `prob` table:

```r
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
prob %>% rownames_to_column() %>% 
  pivot_longer(-rowname) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(as.integer(rowname), value, group=name, linetype=name)) +
  geom_line() +
  scale_linetype_manual(values=c(`2.5%`=2, `97.5%`=2, mean=1),
    guide='none') +
  labs(x='Empathic concern', y='',
       title='Relative Inparty Favoritism',
       subtitle='Pr(etc)') +
  theme_minimal()
```

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, see my post for the correct solution. Thanks for your help!